# Getting \newcommand for lettrine in MyClass ignoring eventual empty line

Tags: macros, documentclass-writing, lettrine

I am committed in writing my class for the university and we want the first section of the article to begin with capital from `lettrine` package and to be entitled "introduction".
I must put this in the class and provide a template to the authors. The example I attach works until you don't start with an empty line between the class defined command `\introduction` and your text.

How to let the `\newcommand` defined in the last line in `MyClass.cls` ignore eventual blank lines left from an unaccustomed or lazy author?

I attach minimal working examples for what i must use (so there will be extra features).

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% MyClass  WORKING EXAMPLE 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/12/01]
\ProvidesPackage{MyClass}[2017/08/30 v0.0]
\AtEndOfClass{\RequirePackage{microtype}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%MY CLASS doesn't support twocolumns
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{extarticle}}
\ProcessOptions*
\LoadClass[a4paper,11pt,final]{extarticle}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%MUST-TO-BE INCLUDED PACKAGES    
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\RequirePackage[OT1, OT2, T1]{fontenc}%Font Encoding
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}%UTF-8 Input Encoding (italian keyboard)
\RequirePackage[polutonikogreek,italian,english]{babel}%Languages. Last one is the main one.
\RequirePackage{authblk}%Affiliations
\RequirePackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,marvosym,wasysym,pxfonts,cancel}%All math symbols ever needed
\RequirePackage{lipsum}%Dummy text i.e. \lipsum[3-5]
\RequirePackage{xcolor}%Adding xcolors 




%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%Color scheme
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\definecolor{color0}{RGB}{0,0,0} % Basic Black
\definecolor{color1}{RGB}{59,90,198} % Author email

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%PAGE LAYOUT AND TITLEPAGE
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\RequirePackage[left=80pt,%
                right=80pt,%
                top=70pt,%
                bottom=80pt,%
                headheight=15pt,%
                headsep=10pt,%
                a4paper,twoside]{geometry}%
\RequirePackage[labelfont={bf,sf},%
                labelsep=period,%
                figurename=Fig.,%
                singlelinecheck=off,%
                justification=RaggedRight]{caption}

\renewcommand{\@maketitle}{%
\vskip60pt%
{\raggedright \titlefont \@title\par}%
\vskip12pt
{\raggedright \@author\par}
\rule{\linewidth}{.3pt}
\vskip12pt%
}%


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%NEWCOMMANDS   
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\titlefont}{\normalfont\sffamily\bfseries\fontsize{22}{25}\selectfont}
\newcommand{\absfont}{\normalfont\rmfamily\bfseries\fontsize{11}{14}\selectfont}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%Author/Affiliation Management
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setlength{\affilsep}{1em}
\renewcommand\Authfont{\color{color0}\normalfont\sffamily\bfseries\scshape\fontsize{15}{17}\selectfont}

%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%FIRST LETTER
%%%%%%%%%%%%
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\RequirePackage{lettrine}
\RequirePackage{yfonts}
\DeclareFontShape{LYG}{ygoth}{m}{n}{ <-> ygoth}{}
%\renewcommand{\LettrineTextFont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\color[gray]{0.5}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%By Reed A. Cartwright 
%%http://dererumnatura.us/archives/2009/02/automatic-usage.html
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand*{\ecap}[1]{\begingroup\obeyspaces\etospace{#1}{}}
\newcommand*{\etospace}[3]{\ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{\space}}%
{\endgroup\lettrine[lines=3, nindent=0em, findent=0.1em]{#1}{#2}#3}{\etospace{#1}{#2#3}}}
% Setup environment `entry' to use `entry*' with a drop cap
\newenvironment{entry}{\begin{entry*}\ecap}{\end{entry*}}
% Setup environment `entry*' so that lettrine can be manually specified if needed
\newenvironment{entry*}{}{}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%CLASS DEFINITIONS
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\introduction}{\section{Introduction}\label{intro}\ecap}
```

And here's the template:

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% WORKIN' EXAMPLE
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass{MyClass}

\begin{document}


\date{}             
\setcounter{Maxaffil}{0}                                        
\renewcommand\Affilfont{\itshape\footnotesize}


\title{Title of the publication} 

\author[a]{Giuseppe Verdi}
\author[a, b]{Mario Rossi}

\affil[a]{University A, address}
\affil[b]{University B, address}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}


\introduction %<==NO BLANK LINE AFTER THIS LINE!! HELP==>
The beginning. \lipsum[2]


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the definition of `\introduction` from

```
\newcommand{\introduction}{\section{Introduction}\label{intro}\ecap}
```

to

```
\newcommand{\introduction}{\section{Introduction}\label{intro}\ecappar}
```

and define `\ecappar` as

```
\newcommand\ecappar[1]{\ifx\par#1\def\next{\ecappar}\else\def\next{\ecap{#1}}\fi\next}
```

Here, `\ecappar` absorbs all intervening `\par` tokens.  When it runs out of them, it invokes `\ecap` on the next thing.

EDITED to make `\ecappar` more robust.  RE-EDITED to make it work with diacritics.

Here is the style file

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% MyClass  WORKING EXAMPLE 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/12/01]
\ProvidesPackage{MyClass}[2017/08/30 v0.0]
\AtEndOfClass{\RequirePackage{microtype}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%MY CLASS doesn't support twocolumns
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{extarticle}}
\ProcessOptions*
\LoadClass[a4paper,11pt,final]{extarticle}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%MUST-TO-BE INCLUDED PACKAGES    
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\RequirePackage[OT1, OT2, T1]{fontenc}%Font Encodingintroduction
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}%UTF-8 Input Encoding (italian keyboard)
\RequirePackage[polutonikogreek,italian,english]{babel}%Languages. Last one is the main one.
\RequirePackage{authblk}%Affiliations
\RequirePackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,marvosym,wasysym,pxfonts,cancel}%All math symbols ever needed
\RequirePackage{lipsum}%Dummy text i.e. \lipsum[3-5]
\RequirePackage{xcolor}%Adding xcolors 




%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%Color scheme
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\definecolor{color0}{RGB}{0,0,0} % Basic Black
\definecolor{color1}{RGB}{59,90,198} % Author email

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%PAGE LAYOUT AND TITLEPAGE
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\RequirePackage[left=80pt,%
                right=80pt,%
                top=70pt,%
                bottom=80pt,%
                headheight=15pt,%
                headsep=10pt,%
                a4paper,twoside]{geometry}%
\RequirePackage[labelfont={bf,sf},%
                labelsep=period,%
                figurename=Fig.,%
                singlelinecheck=off,%
                justification=RaggedRight]{caption}

\renewcommand{\@maketitle}{%
\vskip60pt%
{\raggedright \titlefont \@title\par}%
\vskip12pt
{\raggedright \@author\par}
\rule{\linewidth}{.3pt}
\vskip12pt%
}%


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%NEWCOMMANDS   
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\titlefont}{\normalfont\sffamily\bfseries\fontsize{22}{25}\selectfont}
\newcommand{\absfont}{\normalfont\rmfamily\bfseries\fontsize{11}{14}\selectfont}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%Author/Affiliation Management
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setlength{\affilsep}{1em}
\renewcommand\Authfont{\color{color0}\normalfont\sffamily\bfseries\scshape\fontsize{15}{17}\selectfont}

%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%FIRST LETTER
%%%%%%%%%%%%
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\RequirePackage{lettrine}
\RequirePackage{yfonts}
\DeclareFontShape{LYG}{ygoth}{m}{n}{ <-> ygoth}{}
%\renewcommand{\LettrineTextFont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\color[gray]{0.5}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%By Reed A. Cartwright 
%%http://dererumnatura.us/archives/2009/02/automatic-usage.html
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand*{\ecap}[1]{\begingroup\obeyspaces\etospace{#1}{}}
\newcommand\ecappar[1]{\ifx\par#1\def\next{\ecappar}\else\def\next{\ecap{#1}}\fi\next}
\newcommand*{\etospace}[3]{\ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{\space}}%
{\endgroup\lettrine[lines=3, nindent=0em, findent=0.1em]{#1}{#2}#3}{\etospace{#1}{#2#3}}}
% Setup environment `entry' to use `entry*' with a drop cap
\newenvironment{entry}{\begin{entry*}\ecap}{\end{entry*}}
% Setup environment `entry*' so that lettrine can be manually specified if needed
\newenvironment{entry*}{}{}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%CLASS DEFINITIONS
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\introduction}{\section{Introduction}\label{intro}\ecappar}
```

and the MWE:

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% WORKIN' EXAMPLE
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass{MyClass}

\begin{document}


\date{}             
\setcounter{Maxaffil}{0}                                        
\renewcommand\Affilfont{\itshape\footnotesize}


\title{Title of the publication} 

\author[a]{Giuseppe Verdi}
\author[a, b]{Mario Rossi}

\affil[a]{University A, address}
\affil[b]{University B, address}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}


\introduction %<==NO BLANK LINE AFTER THIS LINE!! HELP==>
The beginning. \lipsum[2]

\introduction %<==NO BLANK LINE AFTER THIS LINE!! HELP==>

The beginning. \lipsum[2]

\introduction %<==NO BLANK LINE AFTER THIS LINE!! HELP==>
\par\par
The beginning. \lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That was quick and painless! i found a new family... thank you a lot.

Comment: @P.Oliva I made a slight redefinition of `\ecappar` to make it more robust.  Please use this revised version.

Comment: @P.Oliva I note that it does not work if the first letter of the introduction is umlauted, for example `\"A`.  I don't know if that problem is from my definition, yours, or an intrinsic limitation of `lettrine`.  Just sayin'.

Comment: Ok! thank you. The aumlaut prob is not at all critical for the use i have in mind but still can be studied for the sake of understanding. And i bet it is a non compatibility of lettrine package. I'll let you know if i find out.

Comment: @P.Oliva Found and fixed the problem.  I needed an extra group around the use of `#1` in the definition of `\ecappar`.

Comment: Right! now looks robust and nice.